# How to make a recycler list view hide/visible on the click of a button in android

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview

I want to open items inside a RecyclerViewon the click of a button and hide the same accordingly. Kindly help me to achieve the same.

Comment: what do you want to hide, recyclerView Item or whole recyclerView.

Comment: @Brijeshkumar: I want to hide entire recyclerView.

Answer (score 1):

there are libraries already available for this

for example:

https://android-arsenal.com/search?q=Expandable+RecyclerView